# How to send image in Stomp Client Flutter?

Tags: spring, flutter, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

```
      File file = File(pickedFile.path);
      final bytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();

      String base64Encode(List<int> bytes) => base64.encode(bytes);

     client.send(
     
        destination: '/app/gifts',
        body: jsonEncode({
          "content": fileName, //userid/groupid/sendername/timestamp
          "sender": userName,
          "userId": userId,
          "groupId": 1,
          "messageType": "Image",
          "imageData": base64Encode
        }),
      );
```

iam trying to send base64 encoded bytes but i get this errors
Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Closure: (List) => String

after alot of searching what i found is that Flutter does not support reflection
any work around or maybe iam doing it wrong

Comment: "imageData": base64Encode(bytes)